# How do I get all the attributes from a class set by an imported module, then store them into Pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have two scripts.

```
#hhh.py module
class HHH:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.some_variable1 = 123
        self.some_variable2 = 'abc'
```

And a script that imported the above script.
The ultimate goal is to create a Pandas dataframe that stores variable names into one column, their values into another column (for exporting later)

```
import hhh
import pandas as pd

# Init some Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['VARIABLE', 'VALUE'])

# Set one column for HHH attribute names, other for attribute values
# So it would look something like this:
# In a dataframe:
#   VARIABLE = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'some_variable1', 'some_variable2']
#   VALUE = [arg1, arg2, 123, 'abc']
```

Essentially, I have varying variables and so many of them, so I can't hard code them. I've been trying to wrap my head around this, but I don't know what it's called -- no luck on search.

Would this be possible?

Comment: Those variables _aren't_ set by the module, they're attributes of a class defined in it. The only module-level variable you're showing is the class itself, `hhh.HHH`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah sorry, I wasn't aware of the specific terms. I will reword my post a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I will just provide you the insight on how to access your data, then you can code yourself the rest of it.

Every `class` object have a `__dict__` method which stores the name of the instances in the `class` and their `values`.

```py
a = hhh.HHH('a', 'b')
```

Here, we are creating an instance for the `class`, with `arg1` as `'a'` and `arg2` as `'b'`.

```py
a.__dict__.keys()
```

Output:

> ['arg1', 'arg2', 'some_variable1', 'some_variable2']

```py
a.__dict__.values()
```

Output:

> ['a', 'b', 123, 'abc']

The `key` of `__dict__` stores the instance name and the `value` stores the value of it.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know that I can call `__dict__`. Thank you!